# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error in change password route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am a beginner in laravel. I wnat to have a change password form in my application. 
my view is like this:

```
<form action="{{ route("profile.changePassword") }}" method="post">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   {{--{{ method_field('PUT') }}--}}
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="old">Old password</label>
        <input value="" type="password" name="old" class="form-control" id="old">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="new">New password</label>
        <input value="" type="password" name="new" class="form-control" id="new">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rep">Repeat new password</label>
        <input value="" type="password" name="rep" class="form-control" id="rep">
   </div>

   <div class="text-center">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
   </div>
```

my controller is like this:

```
public function changePassword()
{
    return view('profile.passwordReset');
}

public function resetPassword($request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

and my route is like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'panel'], function (){
    Route::resource("profile", "ProfileController", ['except' => 'index']);
    Route::get("/changepassword", "ProfileController@changePassword")->name('profile.changePassword')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post("/resetPassword", "ProfileController@resetPassword")->name('profile.resetPassword')->middleware('auth');
});
```

But after I submit form I get an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException 
>   No message

I change `post("/resetPassword"...` to `any("/resetPassword"...` and get a same error again.

Comment: Your form is directed to `profile.changePassword` with a method of post. Your Route only has `get` for `changePassword`. You should change it to `Route::post("/changepassword", ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you form as bad action route, you use the view route and not the post route.

You need to change it for resetPassword Route :

```
<form action="{{ route("profile.resetPassword") }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Woops! Thank you. Bad mistake :/